# agregate in vertical 2 or more colums in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to take these columns (Name/value)..

```
Name   Value    Name   Value  
a      1        c      3
b      2        d      4
```

and join them together as follows:

```
Name   Value
a      1
b      2
c      3
d      4
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the Names and Values static values or the result of a formula? Is there logic required for names that occur multiple times?

Comment: You can record a macro. You just need to cut and paste.

Comment: Names and values are static... not always same number of pairs.. I mean .. sometimes I have 2 names and some others I have 3 names or 10 names.... not always a fixed number of names&values pairs.

Comment: considering only above data, `=C2` in `last blank row of 1st column` and drag it down, `=D2` in `last blank row of 2nd column` and drag it down.

Comment: right. I'm looking for a way to automate this.

Comment: How many such different lists with headers are there?only 2 or more

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable constructed with multiple consolidation ranges (one for each pair) would achieve the result you want (but might be little easier that copy and paste):

[image: SO20012648 example]